# Need to count the array with same key and value pair?

Tags: php, json

I have a json array as:

```
[{"id":447,"file_format":"abc","language":"af"},{"id":449,"file_format":"abc","language":"af"},{"id":453,"file_format":"abc","language":"afs"},{"id":454,"file_format":"def","language":"afs"}]
```

How can i manipulate  this array in php such that i can get a result as:

```
 [
    {"file_format":abc,"count":"2","language":"af"},
    {"file_format":abc,"count":"1","language":"afs"},
    {"file_format":def,"file_format":"1","language":"afs"}
  ]
```

I have tried for array count values which returns the result for single dimension array. Any help would be much appriciated, Thanks.

My code:

```
foreach($occurences as $lsvariable){
            $lvariable[$lsvariable['file_format']][$lsvariable['language']]=0;
        }
         //return $lvariable;
        foreach ($occurences as $occurence) {


              $lvariable[$occurence['file_format']][$occurence['language']]++;

           $language = $occurence['language'];
           $file_format = $occurence['file_format'];
        }

        return $lvariable;
```

This solves my purpose, but are 2 loops really required?

Comment: Use `foreach` and count manually.

Comment: Can you please Show efforts you have given

Comment: what is the `count` field ?

Comment: @rahulsm i have edited the code up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to make an associative array with the key: `language-file_format`

Then to convert to simple array, you can use `array_values`

```
$arr = '[{"id":447,"file_format":"abc","language":"af"},{"id":449,"file_format":"abc","language":"af"},{"id":453,"file_format":"abc","language":"afs"},{"id":454,"file_format":"def","language":"afs"}]';
$arr = json_decode( $arr, true );

$newArr = array_reduce($arr, function($c,$v){
    $key = $v["language"] . "-" . $v["file_format"];

    if ( !isset( $c[$key] ) ) $c[$key] = array( "file_format" => $v["file_format"], "language" => $v["language"], "count" => 1 );
    else $c[$key]["count"]++;

    return $c;
}, array());

$newArr = array_values( $newArr );

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $newArr );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file_format] => abc
            [language] => af
            [count] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file_format] => abc
            [language] => afs
            [count] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [file_format] => def
            [language] => afs
            [count] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, this was what i needed. Thankyou again.

Comment: Happy to help. @ChiragKohli